# Identification of droppings found in kitchen

Tags: pest-control, pest, insect

Can anyone identify these droppings, which appeared in a kitchen drawer and under the sink? They're hard, jet-black, and about the size of grains of rice.

[image]

They look too dark to be from a mouse, and too large to be from a cockroach. And I haven't seen either of those critters around. What could it be?

Comment: pretty sure that's mouse poop

Comment: Unless you have a large group, most mice like seeing you as much as you seeing them.  They will keep to themselves, hidden away when you are around.

Comment: If you put out a trap, guaranteed you will catch a mouse.

Comment:  Been living here over 20 years, never saw a mouse in the house...

Comment: ‘Never saw a mouse’ is not the same as ‘don’t have mice’. The hive mind has spoken here.

Comment: That is  mouse poop

Comment: one more comment regarding a trap:  My mother used this in a partially enclosed sun room where mice were regularly visiting. It consisted of a 5 gallon bucket with a few inches of water in it, a couple of shallow groves at the top to fit a dowel and a tiny ladder from the floor to the dowel. The ladder had small amounts of peanut butter and the dowel had a bit more.  The mice would climb the ladder, then go out to the dowel, then the dowel would rotate and the mice would fall into the water and drown. The nice thing about this setup is it can catch more than 1 mouse without resetting.

Comment: Mouse poop, darn near 100% certain.

Comment: Sure enough, it was a mouse. Snagged it in a trap last night...